# Fat binary validation - (Cocoa [Touch Framework] / [Static Library (converted to framework)]

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, cocoa

.

Hello, all.

I noticed some strange thing.

As all you know there are a lot of complaints regarding "unsupported architecture" error message during validation against App Store when using 3rd party frameworks with i386 slice (for example).

I've upgraded xCode to 6.2 and now I have following situation:

1. I built some simple Single-View application (iPhone) that's using two external custom frameworks (that I built too).
2. One of the frameworks is 'Cocoa Touch Static Library" that was converted to the framework (using custom script) with two '.a' files (iphoneos and iphonesimulator configurations) combined into one fat binary (using lipo).
3. The second framework is "Cocoa Touch Framework" (actually, its static version - via Mach-O build settings), with two binary frameworks combined to one fat binary (using lipo too).
4. When I check both contained-in-framework binaries with "lipo -info" I get - "armv7 i386 x86_64 arm64" in case of first framework and "i386 x86_64 armv7 armv7s arm64" in case of the second one (second framework was built intentionally (manually) with these architectures).
5. When I archive my app and try to validate it from Organizer - it passes successfully.
6. When I check the application binary (from the xCode archive folder) with "lipo -info" I get "armv7 arm64" - so now it's clear why no error message is displayed during app validation.

Have any of you seen such behavior?
May Apple fix this issue in xCode 6.2?

I'm going to test it tomorrow with old xCode version (6.1.1) anyway.

Any input is more than welcomed.

Thank you.

Comment: Hrm. Frameworks are dynamic, static libraries are static. How does your custom script convert static libs (.a) into dynamic?

Comment: Actually frameworks aren't necessarily dynamic. Here are couple of links how to make Static Framework from Static library (.a):  


https://github.com/jverkoey/iOS-Framework  

http://www.raywenderlich.com/65964/create-a-framework-for-ios  

 
And converting static lib to dynamic framework is not my case.